# How to plot root of the complex equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, function-construction, complex, parametric-functions

I want to plot the roots of the complex equation of a1. I have tried the following code but this is not giving me any result. I need bistable plot. How it is possible.?

```
del = -1.5;
g0 = 4.8;
del0 = 1.5;
ome = 40;
A1=0;
B1=1;
k1 = 0.1;
kex = 0.1;
kL = (k1+kex)/2-del0*(k1-kex)/(2*ome);
Gma = 0.5;
Solve[{I*del*a1 + I*g0*(1 - del/ome)*A1*Re[b1]*a1 + 
 I*P0*(1 - del0/(2*ome))/Sqrt[2] + 
 I*P0*g0*B1*Re[b1]/(Sqrt[2]*ome) - 
 kL/2*a1 - (k1 - kex)*g0/ome*B1*Re[b1]*a1 == 
0, -I*ome*b1 + I*g0*(1 - del0/ome)*A1*Abs[a1]^2/2 + 
 I*P0*g0*B1*Re[a1]/(Sqrt[2]*ome) - Gma*b1/2 == 0}, {a1, b1}];
Plot[{Evaluate[Abs[a1]^2 /. %]}, {P0, 0, 3}, Frame -> True,    
FrameLabel -> {Style["P0", Bold, 20], Style[" N", Bold, 20]}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], 
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0005], Thickness[0.011]}]
```

Comment: What are `A1,B1,b` What does it mean `Re[a1], Re[b1]`?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci oh sorry, A1=0,B1=1; b is b1 and Re[a1] is Real of a1, and Re[b1] is Real of b1. because a1 and b1 are complex.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A1 = 0;
B1 = 1;
del = -1.5 // Rationalize;
g0 = 4.8 // Rationalize;
del0 = 1.5 // Rationalize;
ome = 40 // Rationalize;
k1 = 0.1 // Rationalize;
kex = 0.1 // Rationalize;
kL = (k1 + kex)/2 - del0*(k1 - kex)/(2*ome);
Gma = 0.5 // Rationalize;

{a1, b1} = {a1, b1} /. 
  Flatten@Solve[{I*del*a1 + I*g0*(1 - del/ome)*A1*Re[b1]*a1 + 
       I*P0*(1 - del0/(2*ome))/Sqrt[2] + 
       I*P0*g0*B1*Re[b1]/(Sqrt[2]*ome) - 
       kL/2*a1 - (k1 - kex)*g0/ome*B1*Re[b1]*a1 == 
      0, -I*ome*b1 + I*g0*(1 - del0/ome)*A1*Abs[a1]^2/2 + 
       I*P0*g0*B1*Re[a1]/(Sqrt[2]*ome) - Gma*b1/2 == 0}, {a1, b1}]
```

[image]

```
xVal = Range[0, 3, 0.01];
a1 = a1 /. P0 -> xVal;
pts0 = a1 Conjugate[a1] // Chop;
pts = Transpose[{xVal, pts0}];


ListLinePlot[pts, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {Style["P0", Bold, 20], Style[" N", Bold, 20]}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], PlotLegends -> {"a1"}]
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"] 
        A1 = 0;
        B1 = 1;
        del = -1.5;
        g0 = 4.8;
        del0 = 1.5;
        ome = 40;
        k1 = 0.1;
    kex = 0.1;
    kL = (k1 + kex)/2 - del0*(k1 - kex)/(2*ome);
    Gma = 0.5;
    sol = Values@
      Flatten@Solve[{I*del*a1 + I*g0*(1 - del/ome)*A1*b1*a1 + 
           I*P0*(1 - del0/(2*ome))/Sqrt[2] + I*P0*g0*B1*b1/(Sqrt[2]*ome) -
            kL/2*a1 - (k1 - kex)*g0/ome*B1*b1*a1 == 
          0, -I*ome*b1 + I*g0*(1 - del0/ome)*A1*Abs[a1]^2/2 + 
           I*P0*g0*B1*a1/(Sqrt[2]*ome) - Gma*b1/2 == 0}, {a1, b1}]
```

> $\left\{\text{a1}\to -\frac{(3854.71\, -24.092 i) \text{P0}}{1. \text{P0}^2-(8331.6\, -329.861 i)},\text{b1}\to -\frac{8.17708 \text{P0}^2}{1.
>    \text{P0}^2-(8331.6\, -329.861 i)}\right\}$

```
    a1 = sol[[1]] /. P0 -> Subdivide[3, 100];
    pts0 = a1 Conjugate[a1] // Chop;
pts = Transpose[{Subdivide[3, 100], pts0}];



     ListLinePlot[pts, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["P0", Bold, 20], Style[" N", Bold, 20]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], PlotLegends -> {"a1"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using mathematica version 9.0 . Why my plot is not coming for the same code?

Comment: I am not sure, I using M12. Does it produce any error?

Comment: `Values` was introduced in v10. Replace it with `{a1, b1} /.`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Have you plotted the (a1 dagger *a1) ? beacuse in y-axis  it is a1 dagger* a1

Comment: Let's assume `a1=2i+P0` how you wanna plot it? How you define `a1*a1`?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci  if a1= 2i+P0 than a1*= -2i+P0, So a1*a1 equal to 4+(P0)^2

Comment: @vini See my edit..

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci I am using mathmatica version 9.0, this code is not running.

Comment: Probably `Subdivide` is the issue. Replace it with `Range[0,3,0.01]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Please see my code i have written Re[b1] in some places in the equation but in your answer it is not there.

Comment: It does not change the plot and I think it is not necessary, see my edit..